# Regex pattern to exclude numbers and special characters in a string

Tags: java, regex

Regex pattern to exclude numbers and special characters in a string. 
I need to exclude numbers and special characters in the below string.

> A service with name "11.KGGS.003022..CBCL.." is already active between
>   Mon Apr 17 00:00:00 2017 and Thu Dec 30 00:00:00 9999.

i need to use the pattern in tableau and `regex[^0-9]` is not working in it.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: what the output should look like?

Comment: Can you show us an example of an expected output?

Comment: `string.replaceAll("\\W+|\\d+","")`. removes all special characters and numbers

Comment: The output should look like "A service with name is already active "

Answer (score 3):

you can use `replaceAll` like so :

```
str = str.replaceAll("[0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?]", "");
```

**Output**

```
A service with name KGGSCBCL is already active between Mon Apr    and Thu Dec
```

---

I'm not sure if the space consider like a special character or not, if yes you can use this instead :

```
str = str.replaceAll("[0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?\\s\\n]", "");
//------------------------------------------------Space and back line ^--^
```

**Output**

```
AservicewithnameKGGSCBCLisalreadynactivebetweenMonAprandThuDec
```

---

In case you want to make only one space between each word you can use this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("[0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?]", "").
        replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
//------------------^^^^----^---------replace multiple spaces with only one
```

**Output**

```
A service with name KGGSCBCL is already nactive between Mon Apr and Thu Dec
```

---

## Solution 2 :

**exclude numbers and special characters** the rest should be only the alphabetic `[a-zA-Z]`, so you can use also this :

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: isn't space also considered special character?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer mmm, i really don't know ok, i will add another part in my answer which include the space

Comment: @XtremeBaumer in this case also the back line should be consider like a special character no?

Comment: which back line do you mean?

Comment: i mean `\n` @XtremeBaumer

Comment: @XtremeBaumer **exclude numbers and special characters** i think the rest should be only the alphabetic so we can avoid to replace this group of character  using `str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");` no?

Comment: thats right and this equals `\\W+|\\d+` where \\W is all non word characters= special characters and \\d all numbers